# want to fetch image and text to mysql database from my android app via json

Tags: android, database-performance

Please give me some good tutorial and link as well for fetching images from mysql database via json in android and tell me about php coding for that in detail.i don't know much about json. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very broad ,Please have some study from Internet about the things you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please study this tutorial it will give 90% ready made idea :

```
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/
```

Comment: its working i can eaisly fetch data from mysql database but i have some problems in my code i want to show u that,need some help from  u but can u tell me how can i add my code and screenshots with my query.i know this is foolish question but if u have some time thn pls reply me. thanku...

Comment: @jaya I will help you, but as per your question my I have given you a useful link, which also helped you. So please accept my answer, which will boost me up. I will obviously help you. but how I will help you? from here or through email id?

Comment: this is my email id-jayasengar.28@gmail.com

Comment: you can help me here as well thanku...

Comment: satyaki1988.mukherjee@gmail.com -------- it's my e-mail id. now send mail and tell me what is your problem?

Comment: if you have any problem then you can e-mail me, it's a thread just. it will be better to email me.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to create PHP web-service and then call this service api from android application to achieve this for more details [Click here](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for tutorial.